# What is covering my iPhone camera?

Tags: iphone, hardware, camera

Just today I noticed something new covering my iPhone camera lens. It looks like a shutter or aperture blade over the optics, but knowing that the iPhone has neither, I'm really confused. The camera is able to take pictures still, but I can't imagine this would help. I have not dropped the phone to my recent knowledge and I do not believe this "blade" was covering the optics yesterday.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you observe this moving from a cold dry place to warm humid place, then it could be condensation.

Comment: It looks like the padding has shifted. This could be do to a change in humidity. Have you moved recently?

Answer (score -2):

You could clean the lens of your iPhone internally and see what that black object is that blocks the clear view. I've done this when some dust or tiny particles slip into the iPhone...

It's very easy and you won't do any harm with it,  if you follow the instructions carefully!

1. Open up your iPhone according to the tutorial on [iFixit](http://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Installing-iPhone-4S-Rear-Panel/7110/1#.T9YHwtWdD1E)
2. Use a slightly moistened ear-swab to clean up your iPhone lens
               [image]
3. To reassemble your iPhone, just follow the steps on iFixit in reverse order.

If you find a piece has slipped, once correcting that, you can also clear out all dust from your lens and it can solve your issue.

Comment: The piece in question is _within_ the lens assembly. It is not externally accessible. I think the first picture best describes what I am wondering about. Cleaning the lens isn't going to make a piece inside the lens change.  Like I said in the question, the camera itself is working. I took these images in a mirror with the iPhone I am asking about.

Comment: Hm, Ok, but as you've pointed out yourself, the iPhone camera doesn't have any physical shutter. So could you take a picture with your iPhone and post it in your original question? So we can get a better view of the issue.

Comment: I would say be careful with the swab you use if you're inside the device since leaving a film or scratch there is much harder to remedy.

Comment: That's why he have to use a slightly moistened ear-swab. Chances for scratching are at minimum here!